# Why does this expression for finding maximum of 2 positive integers work, being not symmetric with respect to variables interchange?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

My father just gave this solution for finding the maximum of 2 positive integer variables.

$$ \max(a, b) = a * \lfloor\frac{a - 1}{b}\rfloor^{\lfloor\frac{b} {a}\rfloor} + b * \lfloor\frac{b} {a}\rfloor^{\lfloor\frac{a} {b}\rfloor}$$

It is killing me as I thought that any such expression should be symmetric with respect to variables interchange.

Update: abs() was not allowed to use in the solution.

Comment: Is $quotient(x,y)$ someting like $\lfloor \frac xy\rfloor$?

Comment: I think it is @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: Many descriptions of the max function have an inherent asymmetry. For instance
$$
\max(a, b) = \cases{a & if $a\geq b$\\b & if $b\geq a- 1$}
$$
Presumably, your asymmetry has a very similar origin.

Comment: Yes @HagenvonEitzen , it is.

Comment: @Arthur thanks for the suggestion. I would rewrite it in this form
$$max(a, b) =
\begin{cases}
a,  & \text{if $a > b$} \\
b,  & \text{if $b > a$} \\
a,  & \text{if $a = b$}
\end{cases}$$

Here one can see that for the last case you need to choose to write either a or b, which is asymmetric.

Answer (score 2):

If $0<a<b$, we have $\lfloor \frac{a-1}b\rfloor =0$, $\lfloor \frac{a}b\rfloor =0$, $\lfloor \frac ba\rfloor \ge 1$, and so the expression computes
$$ a\cdot0^{(\ge1)}+b\cdot (\ge1)^0=a\cdot 0+b\cdot 1=b.$$

If $0<b<a$, we have $\lfloor \frac{a-1}b\rfloor \ge1$, $\lfloor \frac{a}b\rfloor \ge1$, $\lfloor \frac ba\rfloor =0$, and so the expression computes
$$ a\cdot(\ge1)^{0}+b\cdot (0)^{(\ge1)}=a\cdot 1+b\cdot 0=a.$$

Finally, you will find that $a=b$ will lead to 
$$a\cdot 0+b\cdot 1, $$
which is correct, but asymmetric. With symmetric expressions similar to the given, you might end up with either $a+a$ or $0+0$, both wrong. So the symmetry had to be broken.

By the way, a simpler and more symmetric expression would be
$$\max\{a,b\}=\frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}.$$

Comment: Thanks Hagen von Eitzen. I understand how the formula works and why it was necessary to put the -1. I just don't understand why it is asymmetric.

Comment: I should've clarified that abs() was not allowed to be used.

Comment: Isn't it "you might end up with either $a+b$ or $0+0$"?

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is asymmetrical to make it come out right when $a=b$. So in the spirit of the original, I offer this symmetrical expression:

$$\max(a, b) = a \cdot \left\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\right\rfloor^{\left\lfloor\frac{b} {a}\right\rfloor} + b \cdot \left\lfloor\frac{b} {a}\right\rfloor^{\left\lfloor\frac{a} {b}\right\rfloor} - \frac12(a+b)\left\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\right\rfloor\cdot\left\lfloor\frac{b}{a}\right\rfloor$$

Comment: Interesting how the MathJax algorithm renders `\left \lfloor \frac{a}{b} \right \rfloor` and `\left \lfloor \frac{b}{a} \right \rfloor` at different heights. I can see why, but it looks wrong.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you TonyK!